# HttpContext.Current.Request.LogonUserIdentity.IsAuthenticated returns False, even though the user has successfully logged in

Tags: .net, asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio, authentication

2003I've implemented Forms Authentication on one particular subfolder on one of my sites. My code works perfectly on my development machine, but there is a slight problem on the live server.

If you browse to the admin subfolder, if you are not authenticated, you will be redirected to the login page. The Master Page footer also contains a link to the login page; when the user logs in, that link is supposed to change to a link to the admin page:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Dim link As HtmlAnchor = FindControlIterative(Me, "Login")
    If HttpContext.Current.Request.LogonUserIdentity.IsAuthenticated Then
        link.InnerText = "Admin"
        link.HRef = "/admin/default.aspx"
    End If
End Sub
```

This works fine on my dev PC, but on the live server, `IsAuthenticated()` returns False, and thus the Login link is not replaced by the Admin link. However, if browse to the admin subfolder, I can access the content fine; there is no redirection to the login page.

Any thoughts?

FYI: It is hosted on a Windows 2003 VPS running on top of Hyper-V.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use a condition like..

```
if(HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
```

I have attached an image for your clarification.
[image]

If you see the intellisense of the property you are using, that is used for Windows authentication as seen in the description.

**Reason working Locally:** As you are logged in to your local machine and authenticated by Windows, then it returns true to you, But you deploy in the server, situation is not like that, that's why that property return always false.

Comment: Muhammad, I can access my development site from other machines in the same workgroup, and this code still works. It's also been recommended in various online examples.

Comment: +1 - I didn't read your post as thoroughly as I should have. My previous comment stands, but I didn't spot that you had offered the solution that I eventually came across via other means (`Context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated`).

Answer (score 0):

Try to debug web application not with Visual Studio Web Server, but with [IIS Express](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=abc59783-89de-4adc-b770-0a720bb21deb).